Insert monospace text at the beginning of \item While Using microtype
I'm trying to insert teletype text (monospace) at the beginning of an \item in various environments such as lists, tables, or description lists in LaTeX. I understand that the \verb command cannot be used directly as an argument in another command, and while it might sometimes work without errors, it's not reliable. Therefore, I've replaced \verb with \texttt, manually escaping special characters and replacing spaces with ~. Since I generate my LaTeX document via scripting, this approach seemed to work... but...
I've encountered an issue when the microtype package is enabled. Specifically, \texttt doesn't handle special characters as expected, causing LuaLaTeX to fail to compile when using certain characters at the beginning of an \item.
Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{\texttt{foo}} Bold teletype
    \item \texttt{foo} Teletype
    % \item \texttt{^} Not allowed at the beginning of item

    \item \verb§^§ Teletype with verb
    % \item \textbf{\verb§^§} Bold teletype with verb not allowed
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

When microtype is enabled, the line \item \texttt{^} does not compile using LuaLaTeX, while \item \verb§^§ does compile. However, if I try to use \item[\verb§^§], it’s not allowed.
Given that I have to choose between \verb and \texttt depending on the context, which is not straightforward in my situation, I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to use something like \cde§^#  ab   c§ or \cde{\^\#~~ab~~~c} consistently in any context, with microtype enabled.
Is there a robust solution that works across different environments and with microtype enabled?
Perhaps just fixing the following with some magic would be a solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{\^}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}


Have you seen the posting How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX?

I think that microtype has nothing to do with the problem.

Define a suitable command that absorbs the argument verbatim. You can use verb-style delimiters or {...} if there aren't unmatched braces in the argument.
The optional argument to \vtt is a one-argument macro that's applied on the whole second argument.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ttv}{O{}v}{%
  #1{\texttt{#2}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vitem}{v}{%
  \item[\texttt{#1}]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \ttv[\textbf]{foo} Bold teletype
  \item \ttv{foo} Teletype
  \item \ttv{^} Allowed at the beginning of item
  \item \ttv|\cde§^#  ab   c§|
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
  \vitem|foo| Allowed
  \vitem{foo} Allowed
  \vitem|\cde§^#  ab   c§| Allowed
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


If you plan to use \vitem, you should customize the environment with enumitem.
